# Нет Windows 11 в Grub 2 на Fedora 37

Tags: linux, grub, fedora

При загрузке ПК в Grub 2 нет выбора ОС.

1. Установил на Windows 11
2. Установил Fedora 37 на другой диск
3. Выставил в UEFI приоритет Федора -> Винда

При загрузке пк "Welcome to Grub 2" далее просто загрузка Федоры.
Окно с выбором ОС вообще не выходит.

Answer (score 1):

os-prober поможет grub найти Windowx. update-grub пропишет. Это самый простой способ

Comment: В общем проблему решил перестановкой Федоры. Изначально она была записана Биос типом, а не UEFI прошлой от Федоры.

Comment: Теперь новая проблема, через grub-customizer решил сменить фон в грабе. Теперь он не видит Линукс. В grub отображается Windows boot manager и UEFI firmware settings. Выбора линукса нет.